# Does a removed version of Catalina use storage that generates a "low volume storage message

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, catalina

Early 2015 Macbook air with a 128 GB hd

I installed Catalina, realized all of my 32 bit applications would not run, so I resorted to my older os(Mojave 10.14.6) from time machine.
I now get notifications that my disk is full and memory is running out. I have 2.83 GB available according to "about this mac"
Is there a Catalina hang-on lurking in my machine?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing is to look at your storage allocations.

Open system information and click on the storage tab. If it shows a blank area - just quit all your open apps and set the machine to not sleep for an hour and return

[image]

Once the space is there, if you have purgeable data - that will go away when you need it (and if you're reading things correctly, you'll purge with that little space). If you don't have data that's able to be purged, click on the manage button to decide which bucket needs cleaning.

It's unlikely you have a second OS sitting, but it is possible.

Comment: Curious that there are two Mac HD revealed. One with 62GB as "other volumes in container", and the other with 57GB as "other volumes in container."

Comment: Yes @Hammy I was wrong and you were right. You have two! Want to change the name of one (or both) so we dns help you lose some extra baggage but not the baggage you mean to keep?

Comment: In disk utility, can you eject and rename one of the drives? If so, that would let you delete with confidence the “system” that’s not running @Hammy  Since you can’t eject the running system, it should be pretty safe. I would hate for you to lose data if you don’t have a backup

Comment: Thank you very much @bmike. You have been very patient with me and have helped me solve my problem.