# The disk Macintosh HD can't be unlocked

Tags: mac, disk-utility, catalina

I am getting "the disk Macintosh HD can't be unlocked" popup error after reinstalling Catalina.

I checked Disk Utility, there are 3 partitions named, "Macintosh HD", "Macintosh HD - Data", "Macintosh HD - Data Data".

How can I fix this?

Comment: It appears you are reinstalling over top of an existing install, try a clean install by erasing the drive first.  Before starting this, you did back up your data, right?

Comment: Here is a link to the new question tread: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387440/macintosh-hd-is-locked-unlocking-with-disk-utility-first-aid-taking-12-hours

Comment: Since we might have some other people with this, a second question with more details is here: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/387440/macintosh-hd-is-locked-unlocking-with-disk-utility-first-aid-taking-12-hours specifically, the unlock is taking a long time so it seems like a follow on or new question perhaps.

Comment: Hi, it seems the problem occured with Big Sur update? KR

Comment: Solved: https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/the-disk-macintosh-hd-data-cant-be-unlocked.2269322/

Answer (score 2):

If you can still boot into the Recovery or Internet Recovery please open the Terminal app from the Utilities folder and copy the result of

> du -f

and

> diskutil apfs list

It is likely there was an issue with the install/migration and depending of free space you might have to erase and reinstall the OS (for that please follow the Apple guide at https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/reinstall-macos-mchlp1599/mac)

Editing the name of the drives so [they are unique will help you know which](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/380048) is which.

Comment: What will these two commands tell the OP that will effect a repair?  “Locked”,  is not the same as “full”.  If you want a clarification, post a comment.

Comment: I know locked is different but the hope is with the output from those it will assist with the remaining steps...

Answer (score 1):

This same thing happened to me. I had:

**Macintosh HD**

**Macintosh HD - Data**

**Macintosh HD - Data - Data**

One thing that has changed that I didn't know with Catalina is that when you look at Disk Utility it shows

Internal

Macintosh HD

That version (Macintosh HD) was greyed out for me. I couldn't First-Aid it, delete it, mount it, nothing.

I found that if you go to:

**View** > **Show All Devices**

It will show you

```
APPLE SSD <some serial number>
     Container disk2
           Macintosh HD
```

If you select that top node, (APPLE SSD), and then click erase and put in:

```
Name: Macintosh HD
Format: APFS or Mac OS Extended (Journaled)
Scheme: GUID Partition Table
```

Then it should ask for your **AppleID Password** and then it will delete the volume

Then you can proceed with the reinstall like you normally would.